# Simple modal dialog in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to show a simple bootstrap dialog. My link is as following:

```
<td style="width:40px;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imagesModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></a></td>
```

And modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="imagesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Images</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Angular interprets the link as "http://localhost:4200". How do you just use a simple anchor for an bootstrap modal?

Comment: You might consider using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples.

Comment: you can pass `JavaScript:Void(0);` to `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You try this.**

*component.ts*

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true, size: 'xl' });
}
```

*component.html*

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(content)">Click Modal Popup</button>

    <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Modal Title</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Content Area
            </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Reference:  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Answer (score 3):

Had provided a [Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-simple-modal) so you can check it out

You can simply use [Ngx-Bootstrap](https://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/modals) library which you can implement your modal in an angular implementation:

**Home Module (home.module.ts)**

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

**Home Component (home.component.ts)**

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template: `
       <button class="btn btn-primary"
               (click)="openModal(template)">Open Modal</button>

      // Ng-Template Modal
      <ng-template #template>
          <div class="modal-header">

             // Modal Title 
             <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>

             // Close Button 
             <button type="button" 
                     class="close pull-right" 
                     (click)="modalRef.hide()">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            This is a modal.
          </div>
     </ng-template>
    `
  })
  export class HomeComponent {
     modalRef: BsModalRef;

     constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

     openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
         this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
     }

  }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got a fine modal. However when I try to close the modal it says that modalRef is undefined. <ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>. How do you make the close button work?

Comment: I also tried following.   closeModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.closeModal(template);
  }

Comment: apologies, had updated my answer. Declare the "modalRef: BsModalRef;" at the top of your constructor and be sure to import it import { BsModalService, ModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Comment: No problems just glad for the support. Do you need to initialize modelRef somehow. Its still null.

Comment: thanks. You can somehow refer the implementation here in their docs. There's 2 tabs (Template and Component) so you can check on their Component Tab on how they were able to achieve the modal for additional info and options as well on your part :)
https://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/modals#service-template

Comment: @ThomasSegato had created a stackblitz demo regarding with this implementation. I tested and It's running well here so you could use this as a reference as well and had also updated my answer in relavance to the demo code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-simple-modal

Comment: Awesome! You sample led me to the missing link. I didnt set "this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);" Thanks a lot hoghly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for it and added code snippets from my app.

So here is the full app: https://github.com/shivansh-max/PianshJewelryStore
The main angular project is inside PianshJewelryStore. The other folders are some A.P.I projects for this project feel free to check them out !!!

I had to inject using a mat dialog. So for the mat-dialog, you need to install some dependencies. Here they are (you can install them using npm install):

- @angular/material
- @angular/platform-browser/animations

Then you will have to add it to a component by injecting it into the constructer:

```
  constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        public matDialog: MatDialog,
        private passer: PasserForModalService) {}
```

Open Modal Function:

```js
  openModal() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    // The user can't close the dialog by clicking outside its body
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.id = 'modal-component';
    dialogConfig.height = '350px';
    dialogConfig.width = '600px';

    this.passer.jewelry = this.jewelry;
    // console.log(this.passer.jewelry);
    

    // https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview
    const modalDialog = this.matDialog.open(
      VeiwElementModalComponent,
      dialogConfig
    );
    
  }
```

Where I pass VeiwElementModalComponent you will pass your own component.

Here is the constructer for the modal component:

```js
  constructor(
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<VeiwElementModalComponent>,
      @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
      public passer: PasserForModalService
  ) {}
```

Here is how you would close the modal:

```js
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```